# Bluebird overwriting constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I'm currently writing up my promise chains and am coming across an odd issue with Bluebird. Using babel-node and ES6, I'm trying to create a promise chain that doesn't require me having to do `.then(function() { return foo(); });` but instead `.then(foo)`. The issue is the data in my constructor gets removed when the function is called in the shorter form.

Here's a quick example.

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';

class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    this.my_var = 'Hello!';
  }

  startOne() {
    var self = this;
    return this.wait()
      .then(function() { return self.myself(); });
  }

  startTwo() {
    return this.wait().then(this.myself);
  }

  wait() {
    return Promise.delay(1000);
  }

  myself() {
    if (!this) return console.log('I\'m not feeling like myself today...');
    console.log(this);
  }
}


var foo = new TestClass();
foo.startOne();
foo.startTwo();
```

When `foo.startOne()` is called, which is using the longer version of the chain, it properly returns `{my_var: 'Hello'}`. However when `foo.startTwo()` is called, `this` is `undefined`.

Why is that? How am I writing my chain incorrectly that `this` becomes undefined? Or is it really just supposed to be written like the first example?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a basic JS issue, if you review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work, example #3 in the first answer demonstrates your issue. You are doing `var tmp = this.myself; tmp()` which makes `this === undefined`. Since you are using ES6, use an arrow function, e.g. `.then(() => this.myself())` Issues like this are asked so often I'm not sure what to dup this into.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: We've got one specifically for bluebird promises :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regular Javascript problem with passing a function reference (nothing specific to do with promises).

When you pass `this.myself` as a function argument, all that gets actually passed is a reference to the `myself` function and the binding to the `this` object is lost so when the function is called, the `this` pointer will be wrong and won't point to your object's instance data.  There are numerous ways to work around this.  This is a generic Javascript issue with passing callback functions that are methods.  There are a number of ways to work around this.

You can use `.bind()` to keep the `this` reference property attached like this:

```
 return this.wait().then(this.myself.bind(this));
```